AnimatorStateInfo.nameHash が obsolete だと言われる
Unity初心者です。
Unityで以下のようなエラーが出たのですが、どなたか対処法を教えてください。
Assets/unity-chan!/Unity-chan! Model/Scripts/UnityChanControlScriptWithRgidBody.cs(172,12): warning CS0618: 'AnimatorStateInfo.nameHash' is obsolete: 'AnimatorStateInfo.nameHash has been deprecated. Use AnimatorStateInfo.fullPathHash instead.'

以下の動画の「前に移動させてみよう」というところを参考にしてやったのですが、実行ボタンを押すとエラーが出てしまったというのが現状です。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kobH1qnXVmo&list=PL9coVdSKyb6FY_uIwue18g3OIMgwTptcl&index=2

詳しくありませんが、これは「warning」、つまり警告ですので、エラーでは無さそうです。そのままで動きませんか？ 警告に対処して直したい場合は、そのまま「nameHash fullPathHash」などで検索すると、多少は情報が有りそうです。

この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ 使っているUnityの版数が変わった時に対処が必要ということでしょう。Unity4.7でMMD4Mecanimがそのままじゃ動かない, Unity-Chan! のスクリプトを直す（2020年11月） あとこちらマルチポストなのか同じ学習などして同じ課題に当たった別の人ですかね。エラーの解決方法
